# Sed command to replace a variable's value in a config file with another variable's value in current script?

Tags: bash, sed

My current script looks like this:

```
replacement="Hello"

sed -i 's/\(^TEXT_BLOCK=\).*/\1replacement/' path
```

I want to be able to replace the variable TEXT_BLOCK located in my config file with the contents of the variable replacement. I have tried \1$replacement and \1#replacement# but they do not give me my desired outcome.

Hardcoding it like this works for me but I do not want to hardcode. I want to be able to assign TEXT_BLOCK to a variable's value:

```
sed -i 's/\(^TEXT_BLOCK=\).*/\1Hello/' path
```

Comment: You need something like `sed -i "s/^\\(TEXT_BLOCK=\\).*/\\1$replacement/" path`, double quotes and `$var`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew unfortunately, this won't work for any value of `$replacement`; try e.g. with `replacement="/"`; so I'd suggest using a Perl one-liner or so, instead of `sed` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple replacement `sed -i "s/^\\(TEXT_BLOCK=\\).*/\\1$replacement/" path` will work.
When replacement has a special character, you would like to use a different delimiter in the sed command.

```
replacement="with a /"
delim=$'\001'; sed 's'${delim}'\(^TEXT_BLOCK=\).*'${delim}'\1'"$replacement"${delim} path
```

However, this will still fail when the replacement has a `&`. This character will also cause problems in the "solution"

```
replacement="Hello"
t='TEXT_BLOCK'
awk -v r="${replacement}" -v key=${t} '{sub("^" key "=.*",key "=" r );print}'
```

When you want to catch such a replacement value too, you can use

```
replacement="Hello /& <- strangers"
t='TEXT_BLOCK'
awk -v r="${replacement//&/\\\\&}" -v key=${t} '{sub("^" key "=.*",key "=" r );print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `sed` one-liner suggested in the comments (`sed -i "s/^\\(TEXT_BLOCK=\\).*/\\1$replacement/" path`) won't work for some values of `$replacement`.

E.g., if the variable contains a `/`, you'd get:

```sh
replacement="Hello/"
echo 'TEXT_BLOCK=init' | sed -e "s/^\\(TEXT_BLOCK=\\).*/\\1$replacement/"
# → sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unknown option to `s'
```

Albeit the OP's question is tagged with `sed`, I'd suggest to write some `perl -wpe` one-liner instead, to have a more robust script, and given `perl` is a fairly standard dependency, it should probably be available on the OP's target machine.

To write one such script, you could just rely on the Perl operators [`s///`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#s%2FPATTERN%2FREPLACEMENT%2Fmsixpodualngcer) and [`BEGIN{ }`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END).

#### Proof of concept:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
subst() {
  re="$1"
  str="$2"
  perl -wpe 'BEGIN {$re=shift @ARGV; $str=shift @ARGV;}; s/$re/$str/g;' "$re" "$str"
}

# Usage example
echo $'TEXT_BLOCK="init"\nEnd.' | subst '^TEXT_BLOCK=.*$' 'TEXT_BLOCK="3$/"'

# will print:
#   TEXT_BLOCK="3$/"
#   End.
```

Note that this can easily be adapted to the `sed -i` use case:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
subst_i() {
  fil="$1"
  re="$2"
  str="$3"
  perl -i -wpe 'BEGIN {$re=shift @ARGV; $str=shift @ARGV;}; s/$re/$str/g;' "$re" "$str" "$fil"
}

# Usage example
echo $'TEXT_BLOCK="init"\nEnd.' > data.txt
subst_i data.txt '^TEXT_BLOCK=.*$' 'TEXT_BLOCK="3$/"'
cat data.txt
```

Comment: BTW, regarding the issue mentioned in the recent [`awk` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68511734/9164010), note that [this `perl` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68503512/9164010) is also robust w.r.t. strings containing the `&` character.